# Yarn FairScheduler doesn't distribute resources between queues

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I try to define several Yarn queues so that the cluster will always be fully used and once a new task will be added to different queue the resources will be divided (several workers in the first queue will be preempted)

For that purpose I use `FairScheduler` and rely on the documentation: [Hadoop-FairScheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) and [Cloudera-FairScheduler](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/admin_fair_scheduler.html).

I run Yarn and Spark from Ambari and the interesting configurations which are set set:

In yarn-site.xml:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable=true
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler
yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption=true
```

I define the queues in fair-scheduler.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
<defaultMinSharePreemptionTimeout>1</defaultMinSharePreemptionTimeout>
<defaultFairSharePreemptionTimeout>1</defaultFairSharePreemptionTimeout>
<defaultQueueSchedulingPolicy>fair</defaultQueueSchedulingPolicy>
<defaultFairSharePreemptionThreshold>0.5</defaultFairSharePreemptionThreshold>.   
<queue name="team1" type="parent">
<minResources>20000 mb,2vcores</minResources>
<weight>1.0</weight>
</queue>
<queue name="team2" type="parent">
 <minResources>20000 mb,2vcores</minResources>
</queue>
<queue name="team3" type="parent">
<minResources>20000 mb,2vcores</minResources>
<fairSharePreemptionThreshold>1.0</fairSharePreemptionThreshold>
<weight>10.0</weight>
</queue>

<queueMaxAMShareDefault>0.5</queueMaxAMShareDefault>
<queueMaxResourcesDefault>40000 mb,0vcores</queueMaxResourcesDefault>

<!-- Queue 'secondary_group_queue' is a parent queue and may have
   user queues under it -->

<user name="sample_user">
<maxRunningApps>30</maxRunningApps>
</user>
<userMaxAppsDefault>5</userMaxAppsDefault>

<queuePlacementPolicy>
<rule name="specified" />
<rule name="primaryGroup" create="false" />
<rule name="nestedUserQueue">
    <rule name="secondaryGroupExistingQueue" create="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="default" queue="team5"/>
</queuePlacementPolicy>
</allocations>
```

I have a simple variation of the calcPi example as the application I run (simple while loop which constantly counts pi):

```
        while(true){
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("JavaPipelineExample")
                .getOrCreate();

        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(NUM_SAMPLES);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        JavaRDD<Integer> inputRDD = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext()).parallelize(l).coalesce(100).repartition(100);
        System.out.println(String.format("Data split to %s partitions", inputRDD.partitions().size()) );

        long count = inputRDD.filter(i -> {
            double x = Math.random();
            double y = Math.random();
            return x*x + y*y < 1;
        }).count();
        System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES);
    }
```

And to run it I open two different terminals, first I run the first application (in queue 1). Then I inspect to see that it occupied all the resources and start the second application (in queue 2). I suspect the scheduler to preempt the application in queue 1 and share the resources to queue 2 but it doesn't happen:

Run application 1:

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --class com.comp.CalculatePi --num-executors 25 --executor-cores 6 --queue team2.aa /root/calcpi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

After running it I see in Yarn management panel that 37/54 vcores are used. And I run:

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --class com.comp.CalculatePi --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 4 --queue team1.aa /root/calcpi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now I see 38/54 vcores are used and the application is successfully submitted, although it doesn't start and I get the message:

```
[Timer-0] WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

What is the problem here? Why Yarn doesn't run those two applications together and preempt the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing Capacity Scheduler properties with Fair Scheduler properties.

`yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable=true` is for Capacity Scheduling.
`yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption` is for Fair Scheduling.

In the upstream [Fair Scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) documentation you need:

[image]

Comment: you are correct, this is my bad, actually I did define `yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption` also. I have reseted all configurations to remote the capacity configurations and it still doesn't work.

Comment: 38/54 is about 0.70 and the default threshold is 0.80.  You will need to lower `yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption.cluster-utilization-threshold` below 0.70 to trigger preemption and also check your memory utilization percentage.

Comment: thx for the tip. The problem relied in the fair SchedulingPolicy, the documentation says that this policy manages resources by memory only. Since I set the requirements based on CPU I had to change the policy to drf. I accept your answer since the utilization was also an issue.

Comment: Yeah, setting SchedulingPolicy to `fair` causes lots of subtle problems like you found out.  `DRF` is a better choice.

Comment: I was always disappointed with the fairness of the fair scheduler. Seemed like the programmer could always game it by partitioning in a different way, etc., to create a more aggressive job that would get more resources if they were first. (A paper I read said that wasn't supposed to happen.) I tried preemption, tried everything. Curious if you got to a solution you liked.